# rxjs6 filter Observable<Array<any>>

Tags: angular, angularfire2, rxjs6

I have an angularFirestore observable array inside users.service.ts:

```
$users: Observable<Array<any>>;
constructor()
{
    this.$users = this.angularFirestore.collection('users').valueChanges();
}
```

This is the object class:

```
class User
{
    name: string;
    status: boolean;
    index: number;
}
```

I need to filter based on multiple fields but somehow using the following code in users.component.ts does not subscribes any results:

```
users: Users[];
ngOnInit()
{
    this.usersService.$users.pipe
    (filter((user: User) => user.name == 'some value'))
    .subscribe((users: User[]) =>
    {
        this.users = users;
    });
}
```

My end goal is to be able to filter to include *user.name search string* and user.status == true and exclude the rest of the invalid results.

I would like to do this without pipes. would appreciate any help on correcting and improving upon the existing code to achieve the above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're passing `this.$users = this.angularFirestore.collection('users').valueChanges();` in the `constructor(...)` instead of `constructor() { ... }`. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes, typo, I have since corrected it.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean without `.pipes`? Do you mean with doing `.pipe` on the Observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what your issue is with `.pipe`. But you could also do that once you get your array inside `.subscribe`

```
users: Users[];
ngOnInit() {
  this.usersService.$users
    .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
      this.users = users.filter(user => user.status && user.name === 'some value')
    });
}
```

BTW, it's **NOT a bug** as mentioned by [kunwar97](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7986531/kunwar97). This is the only way you can apply operators to Observables in Rxjs6.

Answer (score -1):

This is the known issuein Angular 6.
Please refer to this link.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1748

Installing rxjs-compact will solve your problem

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

Comment: I have no problems subscribing if I exclude the filter operation. I have also tried installing and re-run, same output. sorry but I don't think its the same issue.

Comment: Not really related to the linked issue